# Reding 3 lines from file - Haskell

Tags: file, haskell, io

I'm writing a Haskell program. More advanced functions later, but for now I'm stuck at reading file. I know that there are tons of threads about it, but as far as I can see, all solution are loop based. I need to read from a txt file with 3 lines. and save content of these 3 lines in 3 separate variables for further use, so loop based solution are not only not necessary but also problematic (with saving into 3 different variables). I searched a bit, found some of examples,  tried to build something from them, but this language seems so strange I can't figure why some modifications are working and some are not.

First of all, working code:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do 
   inh <- openFile "input.txt" ReadMode
   outh <- openFile "output.txt" WriteMode
   mainloop inh outh
   hClose inh
   hClose outh

mainloop :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
mainloop inh outh = do 
inp1 <- hGetLine inh
inp2 <- hGetLine inh
inp3 <- hGetLine inh
putStrLn (inp3)
```

This code reads first, then second, then third line from the file, saves each into respective variable and then puts inp3 on the screen. Thing is though, I don't need to print it just save it into 3 variables for further use, but without the printing line it the program doesn't work, compiler says "the last statement in do block must be an expression". If I however want to print more lines just to see if reading is working correctly and add more putStrLn (for inp1 and inp2) it won't compile. For example, after adding line "putStrLn (inp1)" just after the line with getting inp1 it won't compile and says "Parse error in patter putStrLn, Possibly caused by a missing 'do'? I'm just beggining wwith Haskell so it probably is somethin obvious, but I have no idea what.

There is also a second issue. This program reads from input.txt. I want it to ask for name, wait for person to type and then open it. I figured it would be something like

```
putStrLn "Type name"
name <- getLine
inh <- openFile name ReadMode
```

but it doesn't work either. I will be very thankful for any input that can help me. Oddly enough in example given in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Libraries/Solutions/IO
is using something similar and it compile without any problems, but mine won't. Any sugestions?

Comment: Why don't you return your lines instead? E.g. `mainloop ::  Handle -> Handle -> IO (String,String,String) ; .... ; inp3 <- hGetLine inh ; return (inp1,inp2,inp3)`.

Comment: Because I'm stupid and don't know Haskell well enough. ;) Many thanks, Any ideas about typing filename?

Comment: You shouldn't try to shoehorn in a 2nd questions which is only tangentially related. Just create an actual new question. Also, `mainLoop inh = liftA3 (,,) a a a where a = hGetLine inh`.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I worked it out myself anyway. It appears that notepad++ makes some mess with white symbols and haskell compiler are showing stupid errors one after another. After editing in regular notepad the name isssue is solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that GHC refuse to compile :

```
mainloop :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
mainloop inh outh = do 
  inp1 <- hGetLine inh
  inp2 <- hGetLine inh
  inp3 <- hGetLine inh
```

Right ?

This is in fact very reasonable, you're thinking in (bad) imperative terms, as if your inp# were global variables that you could use in another function after initializing them in `mainloop`... But that's not the case : inp1, inp2 and inp3 are only local bindings that were introduced and can be used only in this do-block in `mainloop` so when the last line is :

```
inp3 <- hGetLine inh
```

It is clear that there's an error since you won't be able to use this inp3 anywhere (you're at the end of the do-block) which is why GHC tells you that the last line of your do-block should be an expression like `putStrLn inp3` rather than an affectation.

It should now be clear that your function `mainloop` actually read the lines but immediately lose them, if you want to use them in the caller you have to return them with `return (inp1, inp2, inp3)` for instance (which is an expression so your GHC will be happy with your do-block). Of course, Haskell is the king of abstraction so repeating the same line 3 times and giving 3 useless names to temporary variable is a bit of an anathema... Other suggestions to do the same without repetition and having to invent useless names would be :

```
mainLoop inh = liftA3 (,,) a a a where a = hGetLine inh
```

which would return a triplet or :

```
mainLoop inh = replicateM 3 (hGetLine inh)
```

which would return a list of 3 elements... But at this point I would probably not create a function just for `[l1,l2,l3] <- replicateM 3 (hGetLine inh)`.